# Binary to Decimal calculator with error report

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, decimal

Wrote a code where I want to convert binary numbers into decimal and if the input contains non binary numbers the program should terminate itself. But when I type number like 1112 it ignores the 2 and continues calculating with the remaining binary numbers.

**It is a Homework for university so it is intended to have this calculation without the binary function.**

```
binär = input()
binärZahl1 = "0"
binärZahl2 = "1"

for charh in binär:
    for char1 in binärZahl1:
        for char2 in binärZahl2:
            if charh == char1 or charh == char2:
                binär = binär[::-1]
                sum = 0
                for i in range(len(binär)):
                    if binär[i] == "1":
                        sum += 2**i
            elif charh != char2 or charh != char2:
                print("Bitte nur binäre Zahlen eingeben")
                break
print(sum)
```

Comment: `int(binär,2)` converts a binary string, and throws an exception if it fails, in case you didn’t know.  No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Sorry, I should have included in my question but it is intended not to use the binary function

Comment: Pertev: In that case please [edit[ your question and add that constraint.

Comment: done it. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `break` only breaks out of the innermost loop. In your case, you can safely remove the two innermost loops (as `binärZahl1` and `binärZahl2` only have one entry anyway...). Something like

```
binär = input()
binärZahl1 = "0"
binärZahl2 = "1"

for charh in binär:
    if charh == binärZahl1 or charh == binärZahl2:
        binär = binär[::-1]
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(binär)):
            if binär[i] == "1":
                sum += 2**i
    elif charh != binärZahl1 or charh != binärZahl2:
        print("Bitte nur binäre Zahlen eingeben")
        break
print(sum)
```

works as intended. Note that you have a typo in your example, in your `elif` you compare to `char2`  two times.

HOWEVER: There is still some very unnecessary loopage. This more often than not leads to errors (for example, you keep flipping `binär`). Minus the error check, your whole code can be shortened to something like

```
binär = input()

binär = binär[::-1]
sum = 0
for i in range(len(binär)):
    if binär[i] == "1":
        sum += 2**i
print(sum)
```

where you still can check for validity inside the loop. A

Comment: Thanks a lot. Code is now a lot easier to read. While the code still calculates the numbers that are not desired, my coding buddies program now works as it is intended.
Thank you very much

Comment: flipping with [::-1] syntax

Comment: (Yeah, missed that flip initially)